# How i can show the frame looks smaller on lower pc resolution?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, size, jcomponent

I'm new in java

i'm trying to make the frame looks smaller in 1366x768 than 1920x1080
but the content of the frame is messed up

i'm using

```
java.awt.Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    if (screenSize.width>= 1920) {
        //frame.setSize(1015, 600);
        //frame.setBounds(100, 100, 1015, 600);
        frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1015, 600));

    } else {
        frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(720, 426));
    }
```

Please check my previous post

[How to resize the JFrame content according to the JFrame size correclty?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54507359/how-to-resize-the-jframe-content-according-to-the-jframe-size-correclty)

Comment: That's probably because you do not use any LayoutManager.

Comment: @GeorgeZougianos you're right, i'm using `frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);`
how i can fix that please ? my jframe already have JPassword Jlabel JTextField

Comment: You will have to use a LayoutManager.

Comment: @GeorgeZougianos so using LayoutManager just a line of code added to my code ? or i reset the design from the beginning? sorry it's my first time

Comment: You will have to set the position of each component (all of them) from the beginning.

Comment: @GeorgeZougianos Alright, i understand, thanks alot